# Delete mails with attachments

Tags: email, mutt

Since I've limited quota on mail server, I'd like to delete large messages. I am thinking of the following flow:

1. Tag all messages with attachments
2. Delete the tagged messages.

The mutt [manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#patterns) have pattern for tagging message according to size range but not for attachment. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about tagging all messages with attachments, but from the `mutt` mail index you can sort by size (press <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>) which will make it easy to manually tag and/or delete large messages.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use the IMAP protocol; it looks like there is no criterion in the IMAP protocol for selecting a message with an attachment (see this thread: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=654086). Selecting by size would be the most orthodox way to do it. If you want to script this operation, you can either use some command line mail client (like `mailx`) or write an easy Python script (which has a support for IMAP in its standard library).